Can a non-commutative $R$ algebra $S$ be isomorphic as a module to direct product of copies of $R$?
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $S$ be a $R$-algebra such that $S$ is non-commtative.
Is $S \cong R^n,~ n \geq 1$ possible?

Since a direct product or direct sum of commutative ring is also a commutative ring, I think $S \cong R^n$ is not possible, as a ring isomorphism.
But if we consider the isomorphism as a module-isomorphism, then it might be possible in some situations.
This is possible as an $R$-module. If $S$ is free $R$-module of rank $n$, then we have $$S \cong R^n.$$
This is because a module isomorphism need not preserve the ring structure.
For example, if $S=M_n(R)$ be the matrix ring over $R$, then $S=M_n(R) \cong R^n$.
Thanks

What are you asking? I believe everything in your question is correct.

An $n \times n$ matrix has $n^2$ entries, so you would want $R^{n^2}$

I updated your title so that it isn't misleading

Do we need to clarify the type of isomorphism (as ring or module ) if we write $S\cong R^n$?

@Learner Yes, because without that clarification, nobody knows which you mean. $S$ is both a ring and an $R$ module, and the notation $R^n$ can also mean a module or a ring.

@DanielCzmmx, thank you for correction. I acknowledge it.

You are correct about the matrix ring example.
For another example, let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $\phi:R \rightarrow R$ be a ring endomorphism. We can define a non-commutative $R$-algebra $R\langle \phi \rangle$ whose elements are "non-commutative polynomials" in a variable $X$, subject to the relation that $Xr = \phi(r)X$ for all $r \in R$. I believe this ring is freely generated over $R$ as an $R$-module by the basis $\{X^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, that is, $R\langle\phi\rangle \simeq \bigoplus_n R\cdot X^n$ as an $R$-module, so $R\langle \phi \rangle$ is an infinite direct sum of copies of $R$. However, this ring is highly non-commutative, whenever $\phi$ is non-trivial.
This kind of ring is called a skew polynomial ring or an Ore extension -- the definition of an Ore extension often includes a derivation which I am taking to be the zero map in my example. My favorite kind of skew polynomial ring is when $R$ is a ring of prime characteristic $p>0$ and $\phi$ is the Frobenius endomorphism of $R$.
